# Jquery Trying to pass value to input box but

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am trying to call a function when link is clicked, pass data to whichever next input box is empty. This is working but value is dissappearing from input box and not staying back.

When any numbers below the input boxes is clicked it calls getno function. This function is supposed to find next empty input box and enter the value passed.
Please help.

My code - html and javascript -

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getno(x) {
    //search for focussed input
    $('input:text').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $gotbox = $(this);
        $gotbox.val(x);

        return false;
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1" value="" /></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1" value="" />

<br/><br/>
<a href="" onclick="getno(1)">1</a><br/>
<a href="" onclick="getno(2)">2</a><br/>
<a href="" onclick="getno(3)">3</a><br/>
<a href="" onclick="getno(4)">4</a><br/>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "value is dissapearing"? when does it dissapear?

Comment: "href" should never be blank when working on custom clicking events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that the page is reloading everytime you click your links. I suggest you set your `href` attribute equal to `#` in your links to stop the page from reloading:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getno(1)">1</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="getno(2)">2</a><br/>
etc...
```

See working example below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getno(x) {
    //search for focussed input
    $('input:text').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $gotbox = $(this);
        $gotbox.val(x);
        return false;
      }

    });
  }
</script>

<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1" value="" /></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1" value="" />

<br/><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="getno(1)">1</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="getno(2)">2</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="getno(3)">3</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="getno(4)">4</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use `<a>` tags for this since they redirects you to a new page (or refreshes the page).
If you need to use anchor tags set the anchor as following `<a href="#" onclick="getno(X)">`

```js
function getno(x)
{
//search for focussed input
$('input:text').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length === 0)
    { 
  $gotbox = $(this);
  $gotbox.val(x);  
  return false;  
    } 
});
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<div><input type="text" maxlength="2"  value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2"   value=""/></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1"  value=""/></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1"  value=""/>  
<br/><br/>
<p onclick="getno(1)">1</p><br/>
<p onclick="getno(2)">2</p><br/>
<p onclick="getno(3)">3</p><br/>
<p onclick="getno(4)">4</p><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the a tag. So add javascript:viod(); as href.

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
  
function getno(x)
{
//search for focussed input
$('input:text').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length === 0)
    {
 
 
  $gotbox = $(this);
  $gotbox.val(x);
  
  return false;
  
    }
 
});
}


</script>

  <div><input type="text" maxlength="2"  value="" /></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2"   value=""/></div>
<div><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1"  value=""/></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" size="1"  value=""/>
  
<br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getno(1)">1</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getno(2)">2</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getno(3)">3</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="getno(4)">4</a><br/>
```

Comment: Typo: `viod` should be `void`.